# Is it secure to submit a form from one HTTPS site to another HTTPS site?

Tags: security, ssl, https

I need to post three strings in a form from the site A to other site B which are hosted on the different servers.

Both sites use HTTPS connection.

My question is: 
Are the three strings encrypted(using site B's HTTPS connection) during transmission across the network? I feel the three strings doesn't be encrypted, but I don't know the main reasons.

Answer (score 1):

When using HTTPS, all form data, indeed all data, passed between client and server is encrypted during transmission.

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS is a secure channel between the client (browser) and the server that terminates HTTPS (usually the web server, but it can also be a load balancer for instance). Anything that is sent between the client and the server over HTTPS is encrypted, its integrity is protected and also the server is authenticated (but the client is not). It means a man in the middle attacker can not read the traffic, cannot modify it (by doing things like reordering packets), and also an attacker cannot impersonate the server (however, lack of client authentication means the attacker can impersonate the client unless authentication is implemented in the application).

All of this implies that any traffic downloaded from site A over HTTPS is secure between site A and the client, and then any traffic sent from the client to site B is again secure between the client and site B. However, in both cases the client terminates HTTPS connections, meaning the client can read or tamper with the data, ie. you cannot guarantee on server B that a potentially malicious user having access to the client has not changed the data downloaded from server A before passing it to server B.

Regardless of this, if you only take the connection from the client to server B, that is of course encrypted and secure.

It's worth to note that due to the way the network stack (TCP/IP) works, some information *is* leaked though. For example a man in the middle attacker will get to know endpoint IP addresses, and also the approximate amount of data transferred in most cases. However, he will have no information from the HTTP protocol (request or response headers, bodies, etc.)